# Linear fit of 3D line using C#

Tags: c#, linear-regression, linear-algebra

I have a set of 3D points that will fit neatly using using a line segment. I need to get the center of that line (no problem, a mean of X, Y and Z will work great for that). I also need to get a couple vectors that describes the orientation of the line in 3D space. In other words I need to describe how much the sampled data's X, Y and Z axis is rotated.

If you imagine an airplane (this is not an aviation application, just a handy example) and the 3d points are randomly spread in the area of the wings. I need to use these points to describe the orientation of the airplane in 3d space to determine exactly what direction the nose is pointed and the location of the tip of the wings.

I have been looking for linear fit libraries but they all seem to be for 2D data sets or are commercial

I could also fit two linear equations through the x/y and x/z data and use those but this seems wrong and a work around.

Does anybody have any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure whether stack overflow is the right place for this question. Anyway, in order to find a line, you could use optimization techniques. You just write the equation of a line and try to fit its coefficients through gradient descent (if you don't know what this is, take a moment to read about it) under the constraint : the line must go through the center. The problem of orientation is different. If you want to find the orientation of a plane, you could have a model of your plane, and try to find the right angles that minimize distance between your plane and the points cloud.

Comment: If your problem is related to the technical implementation in C#, then I recommend you put your code and the errors you encounter. If it's related to "how can I do this", then I suggest you ask this question here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just find a linear regression algorithm and implement it. Even if the code you find is 2D only, it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to add a third dimension. Asking on the stats site is a good idea.

Comment: I see some "multiple regression" code in C# by internet search, that is probably what you should look for.